# Does the LDAP protocol limit the length of a DN

Tags: ldap, limit, max, dn

Does the LDAP protocol specify a maximum length that a DN can take?

I've looked through https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514 but I can't find any restrictions that it imposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't seem to be specified explicitly anywhere - and the Active Directory implementation also doesn't impose a max length on the DN syntax (2.5.5.1).

Marc

Answer (score 5):

Most implementations of LDAP DN's usually hit 256 characters, which I think comes from X.500 still.   After all X.500 defines the DAP, and LDAP is the Lightweight DAP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

According to [that reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259364/535203) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12257178/535203), ActiveDirectory limits the DN length to 255 characters.